# Git, set a branch as non-mergeable

Tags: git, git-merge

I'd like to mark a branch I created in my repo as non-mergeable.

I'm not using CI or Jenkins as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221242/set-branch-non-mergeable). I just need to set this to avoid accidental merge of "experimental" features in the `master` branch.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to prevent other developers to accidentally do this action ? Or do you want to set a safety latch only for you ?

Comment: @LeGEC both of them, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the [protected branches in GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches)

That would avoid any merge unless a [status check](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-required-status-checks) or a PR review is provided.

The alternative, if you manage your own central Git server, on premise, would be to add hooks in order to prevent merges.
See for instance "[`pre-receive` hook on server-side that refuse any push to master which has any non-linear history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5488442/6309)"

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a "native" feature for this in Git?

Comment: @davioooh In Git itself alone, no: a branch has not "closed" associated status, because anyone else, in its own cloned repo, could bypass it. Git being decentralized by nature, that status would not be easily enforced. But GitHub offers more (BitBucket or GitLab as well). If you are pushing to your own Git hosting server, then yes, there is a Git-only way: hooks. See my edited answer.